# how to correctly filter data in a sqlite database?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

i have a sqlite database in which i store messages. It has 4 Columns, the Message, the time it was sent, the person who wrote the message and the person who gets the message:

[Message table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSaTO.png)

Now i want to filter the data for a specific person so he gets the last messages to each person. My problem is, i only get the last messages in both ways(get and send). It looks this way:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myDEf.png)

the code i use:

```
SELECT Accounts_2.Benutzername as Sender, Accounts.Benutzername as Empfaenger, Nachrichten.Inhalt, Nachrichten.Zeit
FROM Nachrichten
LEFT JOIN Accounts ON Nachrichten.Empfaenger = Accounts.ID
LEFT JOIN Accounts as Accounts_2 On Nachrichten.Sender = Accounts_2.ID
WHERE (Accounts_2.Benutzername = 'gondolator' OR Accounts.Benutzername = 'gondolator')
group by Accounts.Benutzername, Accounts_2.Benutzername;
```

I join the accounts database to get the Usernames.

I now want only the last messages that were send OR received. Not both.

Can someone help me with the correct SQL Statement?

EDIT:
CODE to Rebuild Tables:

```
CREATE Table Accounts(
ID INTEGER Primary KEY,
Benutzername TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);

Create Table Nachrichten(
Sender INTEGER NOT NULL,
Empfaenger INTEGER NOT NULL,
Zeit date NOT NULL,
Inhalt TEXT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(Sender) REFERENCES Accounts(ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Empfaenger) REFERENCES Accounts(ID));

INSERT INTO Accounts(Benutzername) Values('gondolator');
INSERT INTO Accounts(Benutzername) Values('Killergondel');
INSERT INTO Accounts(Benutzername) Values('Jan');
INSERT INTO Accounts(Benutzername) Values('TestUser');

INSERT INTO Nachrichten(Sender, Empfaenger, Zeit, Inhalt) Values(1, 2, 
datetime('now'), 'test test');
INSERT INTO Nachrichten(Sender, Empfaenger, Zeit, Inhalt) Values(1, 3, 
datetime('now'), 'huhu');
INSERT INTO Nachrichten(Sender, Empfaenger, Zeit, Inhalt) Values(1, 4, 
datetime('now'), 'verdammt?');
INSERT INTO Nachrichten(Sender, Empfaenger, Zeit, Inhalt) Values(2, 1, 
datetime('now'), 'TEST');
INSERT INTO Nachrichten(Sender, Empfaenger, Zeit, Inhalt) Values(3, 1, 
datetime('now'), 'TEST');
INSERT INTO Nachrichten(Sender, Empfaenger, Zeit, Inhalt) Values(4, 1, 
datetime('now'), 'HI');
```

i used datetime('now') because i actually failed setting it with costum times.

Comment: Include sample data and desired results as **text** in your post. Preferably as a `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for the former for easy importing into a test database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **SQLite** version supports [`CTE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html)s, you can do it like this:

```
WITH 
  cte AS (
    SELECT 
      s.Benutzername as Sender, 
      r.Benutzername as Empfaenger, 
      n.Inhalt, 
      n.Zeit
    FROM Nachrichten n
    LEFT JOIN Accounts r ON n.Empfaenger = r.ID
    LEFT JOIN Accounts s ON n.Sender = s.ID
    WHERE 'gondolator' IN (s.Benutzername, r.Benutzername)
  ),  
  lastdates as (
    SELECT 
      CASE 
        WHEN 'gondolator' = c.Empfaenger THEN c.Sender
        WHEN 'gondolator' = c.Sender THEN c.Empfaenger
      END other,  
      MAX(c.Zeit) maxdate
    FROM cte c
    GROUP BY other  
)

SELECT c.*
FROM cte c inner join lastdates l
ON l.other in (c.Empfaenger, c.Sender) AND l.maxdate = c.Zeit
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wsfDjfkSQVjjQ7TafnBGrH/2).
Results:

```
| Sender       | Empfaenger | Inhalt    | Zeit                |
| ------------ | ---------- | --------- | ------------------- |
| gondolator   | Jan        | huhu      | 2019-07-17 15:40:53 |
| gondolator   | TestUser   | verdammt? | 2019-07-17 15:41:36 |
| Killergondel | gondolator | TEST      | 2019-07-17 15:22:58 |
```

**Note** that the date column `Zeit` must have the format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`, otherwise it is not comparable.